# Как удалить запись из базы данных?

Tags: php, jquery

Я получаю все данные таблицы в запросе в том числе и id. Как можно этот id использовать для другого запроса

[image: Здесь происходит отображение данных на странице]

Comment: предоставьте код текстом, а не картинкой. отредактируйте свой вопрос

Comment: Думаю, можно создать новый запрос и в нем запросить id отдельно

Answer (score 1):

На странице `data.php` делаешь запрос `DELETE FROM имя таблицы WHERE id= айди записи`

P.S. вместо id может быть любое поле из таблицы

Answer (score 1):

```
Delete from `table_name` WHERE id='(int)$_GET["id"]'
```